# Regex Word Boundary Issue

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've had an unexpected issue with a script that was working fine for me before which I can't get to the bottom of. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

I'm replacing strings in a Pandas dataframe column using the below dictionary. The word boundaries '\b' aren't working as expected for VICTORIA. It replaces with `'\x08VIC\x08'` instead of `'VIC'`.

```
statesShort = {'\\bNEW SOUTH WALES\\b': '\\bNSW\\b', '\\bVICTORIA\\b': '\\bVIC\\b',
 '\\bQUEENSLAND\\b': '\\bQLD\\b', '\\bWESTERN AUSTRALIA\\b': '\\bWA\\b',
 '\\bTASMANIA\\b': '\\bTAS\\b', '\\bNORTHERN TERRITORY\\b': '\\bNT\\b',
 '\\bSOUTH AUSTRALIA\\b': '\\bSA\\b', '\\bAUSTRALIAN CAPITAL TERRITORY\\b': '\\bACT\\b'}

test['state'].astype(str).replace(statesShort, regex=True).unique()
```

Printed result:

```
array(['WA', 'NT', '\x08VIC\x08', 'SA', 'VIC', 'NSW', 'ACT', 'QLD', 'TAS'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `\b` is the escape for a backspace character... either use `\\b` or use a raw string... r`\b...\b`...

Comment: You should not replace with regex. Remove all `\\b`s in the replacements. `statesShort = {'\\bNEW SOUTH WALES\\b': 'NSW', '\\bVICTORIA\\b': 'VIC',
 '\\bQUEENSLAND\\b': 'QLD', '\\bWESTERN AUSTRALIA\\b': 'WA',
 '\\bTASMANIA\\b': 'TAS', '\\bNORTHERN TERRITORY\\b': 'NT',
 '\\bSOUTH AUSTRALIA\\b': 'SA', '\\bAUSTRALIAN CAPITAL TERRITORY\\b': 'ACT'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use regular expressions in the replacement part in `re.sub`.

You need to rremove all `\\b` strings in the replacements and use

```py
statesShort = {
    r'\bNEW SOUTH WALES\b': 'NSW',
    r'\bVICTORIA\b': 'VIC',
    r'\bQUEENSLAND\b': 'QLD', 
    r'\bWESTERN AUSTRALIA\b': 'WA', 
    r'\bTASMANIA\b': 'TAS', 
    r'\bNORTHERN TERRITORY\b': 'NT',
    r'\bSOUTH AUSTRALIA\b': 'SA', 
    r'\bAUSTRALIAN CAPITAL TERRITORY\b': 'ACT'
}
```

Note the use of raw string literals where a backslash denotes a literal backslash.

Comment: Thanks very much! I removed \\b from the dictionary values and it's all going fine now. I misunderstood how the word boundaries work. =)

Comment: @ronan I think you understood it fine, just mind that word boundaries are *regex patterns* and they are not part of *replacement patterns*. In replacement patterns, you can only use replacement backreferences (like `\1` or `\g<name>`) as special constructs. Also, in replacement patterns a backslash must be doubled, but it is not a "construct".